# Warning in install.packages : package ‘LEA’ is not available for this version of R

Tags: r

I am running R version 4.3.0 with R studio 2023.03.1 on a windows machine. I want to use the LEA package. When I try `<install.packages("LEA")>`,
I get:

> Warning in install.packages :
> package ‘LEA’ is not available for this version of R
> A version of this package for your version of R might be available elsewhere,
> see the ideas at
> https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-patched/R-admin.html#Installing-packages

I have googled the error and checked out the above link. From there, I tried

```
av <- available.packages(filters=list())
av[av[, "Package"] == pkg, ]
```

With the result

> Error: object 'LEA' not found.
> The LEA package is not available on CRAN ([https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/available_packages_by_name.html#available-packages-](https://stackoverflow.com)L)

I did find it on Github and used

```
devtools::install_github("bcm-uga/LEA")
```

to load the package. It seemed to work but produced

```
Installing package into ‘C:/Users/user/AppData/Local/R/win-library/4.3’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
* installing *source* package 'LEA' ...
** using staged installation
** libs
gcc  -I"C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-43~1.0/include" -DNDEBUG -I.    -I"c:/rtools43/x86_64-w64-mingw32.static.posix/include"     -O2 -Wall  -mfpmath=sse -msse2 -mstackrealign  -c R_LFMM.c -o R_LFMM.o
/bin/sh: line 1: gcc: command not found
make: *** [C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-43~1.0/etc/x64/Makeconf:265: R_LFMM.o] Error 127
ERROR: compilation failed for package 'LEA'
* removing 'C:/Users/user/AppData/Local/R/win-library/4.3/LEA'
Warning message:
In i.p(...) :
  installation of package ‘C:/Users/user/AppData/Local/Temp/RtmpS6n0Nn/file37dc6b032b06/LEA_3.11.6.tar.gz’ had non-zero exit status
```

I an now out of ideas. Any ideas please?

I did google this and read the answers to similar questions, but none solved my problem. I needed to know where the current LEA package was located on the net. @Roland told me.

Comment: It appears you don't have installed Rtools: https://cran.r-project.org/bin/windows/Rtools/rtools43/rtools.html

Comment: However, LEA appears to be a Bioconductor (and not a CRAN) package: https://bioconductor.statistik.tu-dortmund.de/packages/3.8/bioc/html/LEA.html (see "Installation")

Comment: Thanks @Roland. The hint about bioconductor worked.